# Some basic CSS guidance needed please

Tags: css

I never seem to be able to get the simplest thing to work in css. I'm sure it's straightforward, but I've been fighting against float/position/clear and I can't get anything that looks like below. I would post a JSFiddle but there's no point as I can't get near it!

[image: css goal]

The green bit on the left is shown inside a yellow container. I don't really want the yellow container at all, but I showed it there because I'm not sure I could have the green bit without it.

Many thanks.

Comment: post a fiddle..and you are ON for an answer! :)

Comment: this isn't really something you should only get an answer for without learning why it works.  Feel free to join me in the HTML-CSS-Web Design chat if you want

Comment: @Mayank Here's one of my JSFiddle attempts: http://jsfiddle.net/ZQ7FL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really tried hard I see ;)

Start with laying out your framework to have left and right areas then fill the right with top, middle and bottom elements:

```
<div id="left">
    <div id="box">weird box thing</div>
</div>
<div id="right">
    <div id="top">header</div>
    <div id="middle">main</div>
    <div id="bottom">footer</div>
</div>
```

Then style them accordingly, making sure that the `body` is 100% high.

```
html, body {
    margin:0; padding:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    background-color: Cornsilk;
}
#left, #right {
    position:relative;
    margin:0; padding:0;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
#left {width:20%;}
#right {width:80%;}
#top {
    height:20%;
    background-color: Chocolate;
}
#middle {
    height:60%;
    background-color: CornflowerBlue;
}
#bottom {
    height:20%;
    background-color: Crimson;
}
#box {
    position:absolute;
    top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;
    margin:auto;
    width:80%; height:30%; 
    background:GreenYellow;
}
```

See this DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dDSFZ/

Comment: Thank you, Moob. Much appreciated. I trust your '..tried really hard' comment was sarchasm (as is the requirement on Stackoverflow), but I actually did give it my best - I just haven't used CSS before and I find it obtuse to say the least.

Comment: Yup, sarcasm is a pre-requisite for SO ;) Glad I could be some help.

Answer (score 0):

You might just be overthinking it...this is actually a really simple layout to achieve. Beware that without content, nothing will show up (since the divs are empty), so you should assign a height for practice but rarely in production.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <!--head and stuff-->
  <body>
    <div id="left">
      <div class="green"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <div class="brown"></div>
      <div class="blue"></div>
      <div class="red"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
#left { width: 20%; float: left; display:inline-block; position: relative; }
#right { width: 80%; display: inline-block; position: relative; }
.green { 
  position: absolute; 
  height: 100px; /*or something*/ 
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  top: 20%; /*or something*/
  }
.brown, .blue, .red { position: relative; display: inline-block; float:left; }
.brown {background-color: brown; height: 10%; width: 100% /*or something*/
.blue {background-color: blue; height: 80%; width: 100% /*or something*/
.red {background-color: red; height: 10%; width: 100% /*or something*/
```

Again, as a general rule, I don't advise setting a fixed height on a div (esp of the px variety), but for the sakes of demonstrating since there is no content in the divs. Things will get a bit more complicated when you start adding in borders, margins, and paddings, because they add to the size of the box, and if it exceeds 100% stuff starts breaking. Drop this in a fiddle and play with it a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you got another solution from me, its a list oriented layout (the height is static now, but you can easily modify the code to percentages and for 100% height):

HTML:

```
<ul class="cols">
    <li>
        <div class="greenbox"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="rows">
            <li class="first"></li>
            <li class="second"></li>
            <li class="third"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body > ul.cols > li {
    list-style: none;
    height: 500px;
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
}

body > ul.cols > li:first-child {
    width: 20%;
    background: #E6E699;
}

    ul.rows {
        padding: 0;
    }

    ul.rows > li {
        list-style: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

        ul.rows > li.first {
            background: #C5A188;
            height: 100px;
        }

        ul.rows > li.second {
            background: #5AA3FF;
            height: 300px;
        }

        ul.rows > li.third {
            background: #F00;
            height: 100px;
        }

div.greenbox {
    width: 80%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #A6E71A;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -100px auto 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JXaqt/